# For which $n$, $n=x+y+xy$ has no solution in natural numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

For which value of $n$, equation $n=x+y+xy$ has no solution in natural numbers ?

$a)n=100$

$b)n=105$

$c)n=110$

$d)n=115$

$e)n=120$

It was a problem from an Olympiad competition. to solve this I considered quadratic equation $m^2+Sm-P=0$ and if $x$ and $y$ are roots of the equation we should find $n=S+P$ where $n$ is a natural number. but I can't continue this idea to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint :**

Since $x+y+xy+1=n+1=(x+1)(y+1)$,

if $n+1$ is prime, there won't be solutions in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Nice solution. It is hard for me to recognize $x+y+xy$ can be factored if we add $1$ to it. is it known in math?

Comment: I won't say if this is something to be "known". One just observes. I do think though, in every school Math textbook, factorization of $x+y+xy+1$ and similar are asked.

Comment: @cosmo5 you have proved that when $n=p-1$ with $p$ prime there is no solution in integers. Are these the only $n$ ?

Comment: @marwalix Yes since positive integers $x,y \ge 1$ for composite $n+1$. Have I missed something?

Comment: No you haven't missed anything @cosmo5